# Angular 6: setup rollbar to add user data in payload

Tags: angular, angular6, rollbar

I'm using `Angular 6` and `rollbar` to log errors.

I have created a `rollbar-service` file with the following contents

```
import {Injectable, InjectionToken, Injector} from '@angular/core';
import * as Rollbar from 'rollbar';
import {AuthUserData} from '../auth/auth.model';
import {AuthService} from '../auth/auth.service';

const rollbarConfig = {
  accessToken: 'ACCESS_TOKEN',
  captureUncaught: true,
  captureUnhandledRejections: true,
};

@Injectable()
export class RollbarErrorHandlerService {

  constructor(
    private injector: Injector,
    private auth: AuthService
  ) {
    // Add auth user data to the configuration
    const userData: AuthUserData = this.auth.getAuthUser();
    // Add userData to rollbar payload
  }

  post(error) {
    const rollbar = this.injector.get(RollbarService);

    rollbar.error(error);
  }
}

export function rollbarFactory() {
  return new Rollbar(rollbarConfig);
}

export const RollbarService = new InjectionToken<Rollbar>('rollbar');
```

I have defined **rollbarConfig** on top of the class initialization.

The documentation says to add payload like

```
app.config(function(RollbarProvider) {
  RollbarProvider.init({
    accessToken: "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN",
    captureUncaught: true,
    payload: {
       // payload here
    }
  });
});
```

But where to put this code snippets as `app` is giving an error in the class ?

I have to set **userData** in the rollbar payload.

Comment: Please add the error message you have to the question. Edit & update.

Comment: Hi there - You should sent this question to support@rollbar.com or post an issue at https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar.js/issues.  That way you can get support from Rollbar's SDK maintainers.